# Multi-variable analogue of the theorem that strictly increasing and surjective function over real intervals is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

It is a well known theorem that a function over real intervals $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ which is monotone and surjective is continuous.

My question is whether there are generalizations of this theorem for multi-variable functions.

To take an example that I am particularly interested in, given a two variable function $g:[a_1,a_2] \times [b_1,b_2] \rightarrow [c_1,c_2] $ and the families of "partial functions" it defines

$g_x:[b_1,b_2] \rightarrow [c_1,c_2]$ with $x \in [a_1,a_2]$ and

$g_y:[a_1,a_2] \rightarrow [c_1,c_2]$ with $y \in [b_1,b_2]$ where

$g_x(y):=g_y(x):=g(x,y)$

can continuity of $g$ be concluded based on suitable conditions for monotonicity and surjectivity for $g_x$ and $g_y$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you conclude the continuity of $g$, if $g_x$ and $g_y$ are continuous?

Hint 2: Let $(x,y)$ and $(w,z)$ both be points in $[a_1, a_2] \times [b_1, b_2]$. Then 
\begin{align} |g(x,y)-g(w,z)| &= |g(x,y) - g(x,z) + g(x,z) - g(w,z)| \\
&\leq |g(x,y) - g(x,z)| + |g(x,z) - g(w,z)| 
\end{align}

Comment: Conditions about monotonicity and surjectivity of $g_x$ and $g_y$ could well be stronger than their continuity. 

One possible condition, for example, could be: $g_x$ and $g_y$ are (strictly) monotonous and surjective for all values of respective index. 

This would imply their continuity, while the inverse does not hold.